# Why weird characters shown in cout for string variable in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code:

`Card.h`:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Card
{
public:
    Card(string name);
    ~Card() {}; 

    string GetName();

private:
    string Name;

};
```

`Card.cpp`:

```
#include "Card.h"

using namespace std;

Card::Card(string name) {Name=name;};
string Card::GetName() {return Name;}
```

`Deck.h`:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <vector>

class Deck {
    public:
        Card& DrawCard();
        void AddCardToDeck(Card& c);

        Deck();
        ~Deck();

    private:
        std::vector <Card> cardsindeck;
};
```

`Deck.cpp`:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Card& Deck::DrawCard() {
    //cout << cardsindeck.back().GetName()<<" was drawn "<<endl;
    Card &c = cardsindeck.back();
    cout << c.GetName()<<" was drawn "<<endl;
    cardsindeck.pop_back();
    cout << c.GetName()<<" popped from deck "<<endl;
    return c;
}

Deck::Deck()
{

}

Deck::~Deck()
{
}

void Deck::AddCardToDeck(Card& c) {
    cardsindeck.push_back(c);
}
```

`Player.h`:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Player {
    public:
        void Beginning();
        Player(Deck _deck);
        ~Player() {};

    private:
        vector <Card> cardsindeck;
        Deck deck;

};
```

`Player.cpp`:

```
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

Player::Player(Deck _deck)
{
    this->deck = _deck;
}

void Player::Beginning()
{
    Card& c = deck.DrawCard();

}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Deck aDeck;
    vector <Card> aHand;

    Card c=Card("THIS THIS GREAT PLAYER");
    Card& c1 =c;
    aDeck.AddCardToDeck(c1);

    Player P = Player(aDeck);
    P.Beginning();

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
THIS THIS GREAT PLAYER was drawn 
�\IS GREAT PLAYER popped from deck
```

Why does the 2nd line have that weird chars in place of "THIS THIS" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have undefined behavior in this function:

```
Card& Deck::DrawCard() {
    // ...
    Card &c = cardsindeck.back();
    // ...
    cardsindeck.pop_back();
    cout << c.GetName()<<" popped from deck "<<endl;

    return c;
}
```

First, you alias the last element of `cardsindeck` with a reference called `c`. This is fine, and access to its member function is fine, too. Then, you remove the element from the container with `cardsindeck.pop_back();`. From the docs on [`std::vector::pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back), we see that

> No iterators or references except for `back()` and `end()` are invalidated.

And that's the issue here. You are having a reference to `back()`, and that is invalidated. It must be - you are deleting the element in the vector that `c` refers to from the container. Accessing its members then e.g. by `GetName()` is UB, then.

You can easily fix the issue by *copying* the return value of `cardsindeck.back()` like this:

```
Card c = cardsindeck.back();
//  ^^ No reference. The last element is copied

cardsindeck.pop_back(); // Doens't affect the copied instance above

return c;
```

Note that this requires changing the signature of the member function to

```
Card Deck::DrawCard()
```

where the return value is no reference anymore.

Comment: so how should I make `DrawCard` return the last `Card` in `cardsindeck`?

Comment: I proposed a fix in the answer now.

Comment: ok that works. Just curious, why does `IS GREAT PLAYER` still show up after the weird chars in the 2nd `cout` even with that error?

Comment: This is the nature of undefined behavior, anything can happen. In this case, the program reads the memory that was previously occupied by the last element of the container, and this memory might not immediately be overwritten by something else. Hence, parts of it still resemble the state of this just removed `Card` instance.